# DataTables - Multiple Tables in a Single Page Website

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a single page application that has a handful of different tabs.  Each tab contains a large amount of data, therefore I do not pre-load all of the pages (since often a user will only use one or two of the tabs).  When each tab is clicked I load the data.  I recently started using DataTables to with Fixed Headers.  The problem is when I cycle between tabs(all of which have their own tables), all of the headers appear when I start scrolling, then go away as I scroll further.

I know multiples tables with Fixed Headers was previously not possible, however based on the FixedHeader examples it appears you can have multiple tables with FixedHeaders, https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/two_tables.html
In this example, both tables have the same column names, is it possible to have multiple tables with different column names?

I am applying DataTables like this :

> $('#FlightHoursTable').DataTable({
>       fixedHeader: {
>           header: true,
>           footer: false
>       }
>   });

Comment: The scroller extension might be better suited to your needs https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Comment: @Bindrid Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm looking into it now.  It works fantastic on some of my tables, on other tables it moves the header out of sync with the rows below.